# What is the style best practice for commenting out javascript in a django template?

Tags: javascript, django, coding-style, django-templates

In a  block in a django template, what is the best practice for commenting out normal, non-sensitive javascript? The options I see:

1. Django template style comments only
2. JS style comments only
3. mixing options 1 and 2 such as

   ```
   {% comment %}
       */
       long
       multi-line
       comment
       */
   {% endcomment %}

   {% comment %}
       // long
       // multi-line
       // comment
   {% endcomment %}

   {# // inline comment #}

   or

   {# /* inline comment */ #}
   ```

I can make up an argument for any of the three options, and have not found this addressed in a style guide such as https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/. Arguments for or against any of these options I would make include addressing readability, syntax highlighting, intuitiveness, and minimizing final html.

Comment: Sounds like a taste question. If the style does not favor any option, then feel free to pick one.